# Javax.naming.NameNotFoundException using Javaee and Wildfly9

Tags: wildfly, jndi, wildfly-9, java-ee-8

Hello I am facing  this exception when trying to lookup the jndi name in order to do a junit test in my JavaEE project using Wildfly9 server:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.phenomenon-ejb."ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote"
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is the junit code I wrote:

```
public class JunitTester {
    
    @org.junit.Test
    public void Test() throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        CllientSessionBeanRemote gest = (CllientSessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!"+ CllientSessionBeanRemote.class.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(gest.Verify_No_Existence("Multiskan"));
        
    
        }
    
}
```

Here is my jndi.properties file:

```
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:8080
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT=false
```

And this is the output showed in the console when I deploy the application:

```
java:global/phenomenon-ear/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.ClientSessionBean
    java:app/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.ClientSessionBean
    java:module/ClientSessionBean!utilities.ClientSessionBean
    java:global/phenomenon-ear/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote
    java:app/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote
    java:module/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote
    java:global/phenomenon-ear/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanLoacal
    java:app/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanLoacal
    java:module/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanLoacal
```

By the way the handshake is currectly done and my only problem is how to know the jndiname or why is the server not recognizing the one I wrote:

```
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.5.Beta1
juil. 22, 2020 2:08:34 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: EJBCLIENT000017: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
juil. 22, 2020 2:08:34 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@757942a1, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <260479b4>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=desktop-k8fvkco]} on channel Channel ID a12ae3eb (outbound) of Remoting connection 651ca769 to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
```

any advice could help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wildfly Naming subsystem bind entries into the following global JNDI namespaces:

```
java:global
java:jboss
java:
```

However:

> Only entries within the java:jboss/exported context are accessible
> over remote JNDI.

Make sure your business objects are "properly exposed" with the @Remote annotation.

Check: [Naming Subsystem ConfiguraAtion](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Naming%20Subsystem%20ConfiguraAtion.html)

Comment: Hello  thanks for your answer, I solved this two days ago and exactly I noticed that I didn't add the Remote annotation in the remote interface and I forgot to put the answer in stackoverflow. Great answer bro and I am really surprised how did u know about the Remote answer. Fabulous!!

Comment: @MRSkan Thanks, so glad you got it! congratulations!